# How to store data of different size in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, load, size, store

I have 1340 .htk files, named as:

```
Filenames            Datasize
fadg0_si649.htk      (459X22)
fadg0_si1279.htk     (346X22)
fadg0_si1909.htk     (270X22)
faks0_si1573.htk     (512X22)
faks0_si2203.htk     (148X22)
faks0_sx43.htk       (504X22)
.
.
.
```

and corresponding to each I also have one .txt file containing data of different sizes:

```
 fadg0_si649.txt   (14X1)
fadg0_si1279.txt   (23X1)
fadg0_si1909.txt   (34X1)
faks0_si1573.txt   (24X1)
faks0_si2203.txt   (16X1)
faks0_sx43.txt     (42X1)
.
.
.
```

I want to import them to MATLAB, and store them for processing afterwards. My question is, how I can store them in pairs from both set of files in MATLAB in best way? Is there any way to store f.ex. fadg0_si649.htk & fadg0_si649.txt or   fadg0_si1279.htk & fadg0_si1279.txt ?

Comment: I think you're looking for [cells](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). You may also consider [structs](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cell-vs-struct-arrays.html).

Comment: I would propose using structs. You can make it so, that the data can then be accessed as ``data.fadg0_si649.htk`` and ``data.fadg0su649.htk``. Therefore you can initialise ``data = struct()`` and loop over ``filenames`` and their ``ending``: resulting in something like ``data.(filename).(ending) = load(fullfile(path_to_data, filename, ending))``. This seems quite comfortable to me.